# Displaying highchart and using php to get data for the chart from mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

Highchart is not displaying anything when i read data from database and use it to display chart.

```
$.post('ajax/like_get_option1.php' , function(data){op1= data;}); //php file is called which connects to database and echo out the result
$.post('ajax/like_get_option2.php' , function(data){op2= data;});
$.post('ajax/like_get_option3.php' , function(data){op3= data;});
$.post('ajax/like_get_option4.php' , function(data){op4= data;});
$.post('ajax/like_get_option5.php' , function(data){op5= data;});
$.post('ajax/like_get_option6.php' , function(data){op6= data;});


     var arr = [op1,op2,op3,op4,op5,op6]; //making array of all the values to pass in highchart

    var options = {
        chart:{
        type: 'column',
        margin: 150,
        options3d:{
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 10,
            beta: 25,
            depth: 70,
            viewDistance: 25
        }


    },
    title:{
        text: 'Demo'
    },
    subtitle:{
        text:'Test'
    },
    plotOptions:{
        column:{
            depth: 25
        }
    },
     xAxis: {
            categories:['x','y','z','a','b','c']
        },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Poll',
            data: arr
        }]

    };


var y = $('#container');  

var tween4 =y.highcharts(options); // passing values to highchart
```

i just need to access my database to get values and pass it into highchart. Any suggestions will be appreciated??

Comment: which high chart is it
for ex : basic, spline with symbols,etc

Comment: Its column chart with 3-d effect. @chetan naik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $.post('ajax/like_get_option1.php' , function(data){
        op1= parseInt(data);
        $.post('ajax/like_get_option2.php' , function(data){op2= parseInt(data);
            $.post('ajax/like_get_option3.php' , function(data){op3= parseInt(data);
            $.post('ajax/like_get_option4.php' , function(data){op4=parseInt(data);
            $.post('ajax/like_get_option5.php' , function(data){op5= parseInt(data);
            $.post('ajax/like_get_option6.php' , function(data){op6= parseInt(data);
            high_chart() ;
            })       
            })                                                                                                                                
            })
            })
            })
            });
```

I used simple loops to execute ajax calls one inside other and then called highchart in the end and it worked. Also i was passing data directly from php file to highchart which was coming string. So i used parseInt to convert the values in int and it worked after some ordeal.

Answer (score 0):

simple highchart graph with data from mysql database

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },
    <?php 
    $sql = 'SELECT count(*) as counter FROM example limit 12';
    mysql_select_db('test_db');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

    echo 'series: [{
        name: 'Example',
        data: [
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['counter'].",";
       }]
    }]';
    ?>
});
});
```

Comment: I have 6 tables with each table giving unique value to be displayed on the chart as a column. I can't use inline php as it will be a lot of complications in my js code. I need to use post request to get data and pass it to chart

Answer (score 0):

you can use implode function in php to split the array with comma and be converted into string

```
series: [{
    name: 'Poll',
        data: [<?php echo implode(",",$arr); ?>]
    }]
};
```

result

```
data : [op1,op2,op3....]
```

Comment: The file is .js . php tag will not work in that. That's why we write php separately and call it.

Answer (score 0):

The general problem with your code is that you init chart before calling all ajax. You should use `$.when() then()` jquery and init chart in callback.

Comment: $.when($.post('ajax/like_get_option1.php' , function(data){op1= data;}),
$.post('ajax/like_get_option2.php' , function(data){op2= data;}),
).  then( tween4 = $('#container').highcharts({
    chart:{
        type: 'column',
        margin: 150,
    },
     xAxis: {
            categories:['x'.'y']
        },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: "Poll",
            data: [op1, op2]
        }]
    
    
}) );

Comment: Are you talking about the above usage of when and then? I am comparatively new to jquery so bear with me. The chart is still empty with no data in it. I understand that i have to complete all ajax calls before passing the value to highchart but still its hung somewhere.

Comment: Yes escaly, you need to all ajax and then init chart. Run a console (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui) and check what kind of errors do you receive.